# What's the best way to add the LESS preprocessor to a WordPress theme?

Tags: css

I have looked for a good plugin for using LESS in a WordPress theme and the most relevant options I've found are:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bw-less-css/ (last updated 6 years ago)
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-less-to-css/ (last updated 4 years ago)
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-less/ (last updated 3 years ago)

LESS still seems to be a good CSS preprocessor and many people use it so why am I having trouble finding an updated solution for that?

Comment: by "Using LESS in a theme" do you mean in /wp-admin/ on your browser you want to use LESS? or in your wp-content/themes/custom_theme/ you want to use .less? If that latter, most developers would find their own solutions instead of a plugin, thats why so little results. For example the editor I use, Atom, has a package called less-compiler that compiles .less on file-save. Prior to that I would just use the JS CDN version of less while developing, than compile with command line on completion.

Comment: I mean on wp-content/themes/custom_theme/. The WP-LESS just do that, but doesn't have an update for more than 3 years... About the editor you mentioned, it just saves the final CSS file just compiled so we don't need to upload the .less file at all, but just the generated .css one. Yes, makes sense...

Comment: I use [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) editor and it has a package called [LESS-build](https://github.com/berfarah/LESS-build-sublime) that compile LESS saving it as CSS file. Cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment of [David Sword](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/132362/david-sword) I realized that doesn't exist a best way to use LESS on a WordPress theme, but several ways to do that. And a good way is to use the resources of a good text editor. I'm used to work with Sublime Text 3 but after trying several times to make it work with no success I decided to use another text editor, [Crunch 2](https://getcrunch.co), and with it I didn't have any problem to compile the .less file to .css, as this is a normal feature of the free version.

Comment: VSCode by MS can do that in one or two clicks.It's free and currently very popular.

Comment: The Crunch 2 link in your answer seems broken (16.02.2022)